# Any way to use STL algorithm to shuffle two vectors simultaneously in C++?

Tags: c++, random, shuffle

I am porting a Java program to C++. I have a piece of code to shuffle two arrays simultaneously in Java, which produces a way to return the indices of the shuffled array so could to used to relocate another array (of the same length) accordingly. In C++, I shuffle the vectors with the following algorithm

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(void) {

    vector<int> A, B;
 
    for (int n=0; n<10; n++) {
        A.push_back(n);
        B.push_back(n);
    }
    
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> rnd(0, A.size()-1);
    for (int n=0; n<A.size(); n++) {
        int m = rnd(gen);
        std::swap(A[n], A[m]);
        std::swap(B[n], B[m]);
    }
    
    for (auto it: A) cout << it << " ";
    cout << endl;
    for (auto it: B) cout << it << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It works. But I wonder if there is any STL algorithm that can simultaneously shuffle two or more containers.

Comment: Do you need to actually shuffle two containers, or could you shuffle, say, an array initialized to `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`? (To get the `i`th element of the shuffled `A`, you would use `A[shuffled[i]]` Instead of `A[i]`.) I guess this depends on how the arrays will be accessed. If access is not centralized, this "auxiliary shuffle" is prone to break through forgetfulness.

Comment: Oh, another detail to check: you presented a pair of `vector`s. Can this be replaced by a `vector` of `pair`s?

Comment: Why don't you std:: shuffle? This would replace your loop. Second thing, why should stl provide an algorithm that process multiple containers at the same time? What kind of advantage do you expect?

Comment: @JaMiT, to shuffle an array of indices and pick up the corresponding entries from the shuffled indices is one way to do that. But it requires additional storage for the indices and I doubt if there needs more space to copy the data back to the vector in place. To se vector<pair> instead and shuffle from there is another way, but the source of data are given as two vectors, this requires additional operations and space too The actual data are quite big, additional copy, paste and move will make it too slow. I tried your idea but seems the loop method shown above is better so far.

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan, using std::shuffle will not shuffle two containers in the same way, will it? I am saying stl should provide that or not, I just wonder if there is any way std::shuffle will provide the indices after shuffle or any way to implement stl-like algorithm to do work or not.

Comment: if you look `std::random_shuffle` it is implemented the same way you are implementing.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Comment: You might provide **same** (copy) generator to `std::shuffle`.

Comment: A simple counting argument shows that your shuffle is NOT uniform. And no, it is not the same way as the standard random shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

edit: Armin deleted his answer, so mine seems out of context. Let's expand

tl;dr No, there is no function in the STL that applies the same shuffle to multiple containers. The STL is pretty big, but cannot do everything. There are just too many specific requirements for algorithms. Wat you're asking is not that common practice.

**However**, nothing keeps you from writing your own algorithms. For instance, you can copy the algo [shown on `std::shuffle` on cppreference.com (third version)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) and modify it.

```cpp
#include <iterator>

template<class URBG, class RandomIt1, class RandomIt2>
static void SameShuffleToMany(URBG&& g, RandomIt1 first1, RandomIt1 last1, RandomIt2 first2) {
    using diff_t = typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt1>::difference_type;
    using distr_t = std::uniform_int_distribution<diff_t>;
    using param_t = typename distr_t::param_type;

    distr_t D;
    diff_t n = last1 - first1;
    for (diff_t i = n-1; i > 0; --i) {
        diff_t j = D(g, param_t(0, i));
        std::swap(first1[i], first1[j]);
        std::swap(first2[i], first2[j]);
    }
}
```

Heck, you could even use variadic template parameter to do more then 2 containers in parallel.

However, there are multiple solutions to this problems, as suggested in the comments. Each solution has it's own pros and cons. I did a speed bench below. However, the solutions by Armin and Jamit will require additional memory to store the new indices and targets for the reorder output.

---

## Old answer

I made some comparison bench code

```cpp
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

static constexpr auto N = 1000;

static std::vector<int> CreateVector() {
    std::vector<int> out;
    out.reserve(N);
    std::generate_n(back_inserter(out), N,
        [gen = std::mt19937(std::random_device{}())] () mutable { return gen();}
    );
    return out;
}

static void BM_Original(benchmark::State& state) {
    auto a = CreateVector();
    auto b = a; // elementwise copy

    for (auto _ : state) {
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> rnd(0, a.size()-1);
        for (int n = 0; n < a.size(); ++n) {
            int m = rnd(gen);
            std::swap(a[n], a[m]);
            std::swap(b[n], b[m]);
        }
    }

    if (!std::equal(cbegin(a), cend(a), cbegin(b)))
        std::cout << "Vectors are not equal!\n";
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(BM_Original);

static void BM_Jamit(benchmark::State& state) {
    auto a = CreateVector();
    auto b = a; // elementwise copy

    for (auto _ : state) {
        std::vector<int> idx(N);
        std::iota(begin(idx), end(idx), 0);
        std::mt19937 g(std::random_device{}());
        std::shuffle(begin(idx), end(idx), g);
        std::vector<int> aout; aout.reserve(N);
        std::transform(cbegin(idx), cend(idx), back_inserter(aout), [&](int i) { return a[i]; });
        a = std::move(aout);
        std::vector<int> bout; bout.reserve(N);
        std::transform(cbegin(idx), cend(idx), back_inserter(aout), [&](int i) { return b[i]; });
        b = std::move(bout);
    }

    if (!std::equal(cbegin(a), cend(a), cbegin(b)))
        std::cout << "Vectors are not equal!\n";
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(BM_Jamit);

static void BM_Armin(benchmark::State& state) {
    auto a = CreateVector();
    auto b = a; // elementwise copy

    for (auto _ : state) {
        const unsigned int seedValue = std::random_device()();
        std::mt19937 uniformRandomBitGenerator{};
        uniformRandomBitGenerator.seed(seedValue);
        std::shuffle(begin(a), end(a), uniformRandomBitGenerator);
        uniformRandomBitGenerator.seed(seedValue);
        std::shuffle(begin(b), end(b), uniformRandomBitGenerator);
    }

    if (!std::equal(cbegin(a), cend(a), cbegin(b)))
        std::cout << "Vectors are not equal!\n";
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(BM_Armin);


#include <iterator>

template<class URBG, class RandomIt1, class RandomIt2>
static void SameShuffleToMany(URBG&& g, RandomIt1 first1, RandomIt1 last1, RandomIt2 first2) {
    using diff_t = typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt1>::difference_type;
    using distr_t = std::uniform_int_distribution<diff_t>;
    using param_t = typename distr_t::param_type;

    distr_t D;
    diff_t n = last1 - first1;
    for (diff_t i = n-1; i > 0; --i) {
        diff_t j = D(g, param_t(0, i));
        std::swap(first1[i], first1[j]);
        std::swap(first2[i], first2[j]);
    }
}

static void BM_Mine(benchmark::State& state) {
    auto a = CreateVector();
    auto b = a; // elementwise copy

    for (auto _ : state) {
        std::mt19937 g{std::random_device{}()};
        SameShuffleToMany(g, begin(a), end(a), begin(b));
    }

    if (!std::equal(cbegin(a), cend(a), cbegin(b)))
        std::cout << "Vectors are not equal!\n";
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(BM_Mine);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

The resulting CPU times are:

- Original: 108600 ns
- Jamit: 76000 ns
- Armin: 122000 ns
- Mine: 102000 ns

[link to QuickBench](https://quick-bench.com/q/i-RhKHoK4u532NbRKaYgUVfpeIg) Let me know if this works for you. I don;t think link sharing there works as good as for GodBolt.

Comment: The OPs original solution is wrong. It is not uniform.